# My Web Services page not running when i change root directory on live server asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

My web services page not working when I change the root directory of my project in live server.

The first directory I was using is

```
       https://ezitasker.com/App/Allporject.asmx
```

which was working fine. Now I just changed my root directory to `https://ezitasker.com/cp/App/Allproject.asmx`. Now all my project files working fine except the asmx file which throws an error:

> Could not create type 'Time_Doctor_WebApp.App.Allproject'.
>
> Line 1:  <%@ WebService Language="C#" Codebehind="Allproject.asmx.cs" Class="Time_Doctor_WebApp.App.Allproject" %>
>
> Source File: /Cp/App/allproject.asmx    Line: 1

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3690.0

The code-behind file is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace Time_Doctor_WebApp.App
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Allproject : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [webmethod]
    }
```

I searched so many things but not get any help. Change to previous root directory work perfectly but I need at new root directory to work my files.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Have another look at the error -- the problem is in the asmx file:

```
Source File: /Cp/App/allproject.asmx Line: 1
```

Check the first line of the asmx file and make sure `CodeBehind="..."` still points to the right place.

Comment: Dear it still giving me error while i change the path

Comment: I just noticed something, maybe it's a typo. The first directory that was working you said was `.../Allporject.asmx`. Notice the spelling. That not the same as the second one. Is that the problem?

Comment: it was not a problem .i checked it .